# Separate an object into smaller objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object, puppeteer

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const options = ["iframe"]
const url = 'https://www.loungeincomfort.com.au/'
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(url);
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    const frame = await page.$$eval(options[i], e => e.map(a => {
        const attrs = a.getAttributeNames();
        const len = attrs.length;
        const test = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            //test[attrs[i]].push({ label: "Hello World" })
            test[attrs[i]] = a.getAttribute(attrs[i])
        }
        return test;
    }))
    console.log(frame);
}
await browser.close();
})();
```

output is like this:

```
[{
    "width": "1170",
    "height": "490",
    "style": "visibility: visible; width: 100%; margin-left: 0px; height: 301.538px; margin-top: -3.26923px; position: absolute;"
}]
```

I want to separate the style output into objects to be like this

I did some research about it and I couldn't find anything useful

```
[{
    "width": "1170",
    "height": "490",
    "style": {
           "visibility": "visible",
           "width": "100%",
           "margin-left": "0px",
           "height": "301.538px",
           "margin-top": "-3.26923px",
            "position": "absolute"

}}]
```

I hope you help me solve this problem if possible
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this:

```js
let s = "visibility: visible; width: 100%; margin-left: 0px; height: 301.538px; margin-top: -3.26923px; position: absolute;"

let res = Object.fromEntries(s.split(';').map(item => item.split(':').map(subitem => subitem.trim())))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
data = [{
  "width": "1170",
  "height": "490",
  "style": "visibility: visible; width: 100%; margin-left: 0px; height: 301.538px; margin-top: -3.26923px; position: absolute;"
}];
//console.log(data);
data.map(
  (item) => {
  // use a tmp variable to replace the style 
  const tmp = item.style;
  item.style={};
  tmp
  // split the style string into an array
  .split(';')
  // split individual items into keyvalue array
  .map((keyvalue) => keyvalue.split(':')
  // trim key and value
  .map(item=>item.trim()))
  // remove invalid values
  .filter((keyvalue)=>keyvalue.length===2)
  // assign to style
  .map((keyvalue)=>{item.style[keyvalue[0]]=keyvalue[1]})
  return item;
  }
)
console.log(data)
```

Result

```
[
  {
    "width": "1170",
    "height": "490",
    "style": {
      "visibility": "visible",
      "width": "100%",
      "margin-left": "0px",
      "height": "301.538px",
      "margin-top": "-3.26923px",
      "position": "absolute"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

For the type of data you have, this will work:

```
Object.fromEntries(style.split('; ').map( item => item.split(': ')))
```

test:

```
const style = "visibility: visible; width: 100%; margin-left: 0px; height: 301.538px; margin-top: -3.26923px; position: absolute;"
const styleObj = Object.fromEntries(style.split('; ').map( item => item.split(': ')));
// use styleObj
```

result:
[image]

Comment: your answer really solves my problem but It doesn't work with my code above

Comment: What I mean is I get this error UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Comment: @MohamedEssam Oooh I see!
Well, so it means that your data is not always as you think it is.'split' is a function of String. 
Maybe add validation before splitting? I mean - check the value is not null before splitting.